# How to get the current post type in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-post-type

I want to change several background colors via "post type".
I don't know how to query the "post type".
I know, that my code is 100% wrong. I searched the web for a solution. But couldn't find any, that would work.

```
(function() {
    var elements, posttype;

    function init() {
        elements = document.querySelectorAll('.color');
        posttype = get_post_type();

    }

    function checkColor() {
        if (posttype === 'veranstaltung') {
            element.classList.add('pink');
            element.classList.remove('color');
        } else if (posttype === 'ausstellung') {
            element.classList.add('green');
            element.classList.remove('color')
        } else if (posttype === 'digitale-events') {
            element.classList.add('red');
            element.classList.remove('color')
        }
    }


    init();
    checkColor();


})();
```

Comment: Do you write out the property somewhere on the page to look it up? (not sure how this works in wordpress) Seems odd you would not use the post type in the template and set a class so you would not have to do this in the JavaScript.

Comment: I hope, i understand your question right. English isn*t my native language.
What i know is that, Wordpress deposites the posttype and other stuff in the database, when the post is created. I have to do it in Javascript. Because i want to change the colors of some Navs to.

Answer (score 0):

One method is javascript if you create a function inside function.php which you have to call all the custom post type and return all the post with ajax in javascript which I do not suggest,  the second method is to [create a custom page](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) and display all the [custom post type](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/post-types/working-with-custom-post-types/) with php, and then you have to do a condition to check which post type is the post and then add a custom class to each custom post type.*Note: This get all posts of a custom type use:

```
$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => 'custom',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order'  => 'ASC'
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try that.
I think i understood it. but i'am not shure, i can get it to work.

Comment: @DerJaeger just follow what I have said in second method and you can do it with some search on the google :)

Comment: I have to create a different custom page for every post type, right?

Comment: no, only one page and get all the posts from custom post type the code whic I have used on the answer